# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

Tags: python-3.x

can someone help me fix the error.
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

i want to remove "testdir" from the variable list

```
root@test/tmp # python3 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    del element['testdir']
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion
```

1.py:

```
import json, subprocess, os, sys, shutil, time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

os.system('curl -s -u xxxxx > list.txt')

with open('list.txt') as data_file:    
    list = json.load(data_file)
    for element in list: 
        del element['testdir']

for dir in list:
    print('dir' + dir)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, i.e. they cannot be modified. What were you expecting to happen? Please [edit] to clarify. LMK when you do and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: I edited it, hope it is understandable now

Comment: BTW `list` and `dir` are bad names since they're the names of builtins. Instead you could use, say, `L` and `directory`.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense. It would if `element` were a dict, but of course it's not. Are you trying to filter out a particular string from the list?

Comment: yes i am trying to remove the particular string testdir

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) to filter out unwanted elements:

```
L = [x for x in json.load(data_file) if x != 'testdir']
```

BTW `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), so I changed it.